# Moving hard drive from old laptop to new laptop

Tags: windows, hard-disk, bios, disk-encryption

## The story

On my old laptop (Asus K56CB) I was running Linux Mint, the drive was also encrypted since Mint was first installed, for clarity. Eventually this laptop broke and I recently got a Lenovo ThinkPad T440s. When it arrived I swapped the hard drives over so I would have the same software and files as I did on my old laptop.

## The result

I didn't expect this to go flawlessly, I expected there to be some errors down the way, drivers configured for hardware that are no longer there etc. However it didn't even want to boot to the point of asking for decryption password. It boots up and not seeing the drive that originally came with (an SSD with windows installed) it gives me a few options, one of which is the new drive from my old laptop. When I select it I just get put back to the same screen.

## My theory

There was mention of *windows boot manager*. My BIOS and booting knowledge isn't the best but I do also know that this new laptop comes with UEFI (which I think is NOT legacy?) so in effort to spped up boot time it has the windows boot manager in the BIOS or something? Either way, currently, on this new laptop with the new SSD drive that originally had Windows I've now installed Manjaro for the time being, having chose the *erase everything option* during installation. I think I'll try swapping in the old hard drive again now to see how it goes. Also maybe revert to lecagy BIOS.

As mentioned I don't have much knowledge about all this booting/BIOS malarkey. Any advice, thoughts, opinions would be greatly appreciated as well as an answer to the problem. I'm aware this isn't a straight forward question but if it were I'd google it.

Comment: So, in the end you have a Manjaro system that boots and runs on this new laptop?

Comment: Yes but I want the hard drive from my old laptop that has mint, config files, personal data etc.

Comment: If your laptop has a second drive bay, add the old disk to that.  Or buy an adapter to plug the SSD into a USB port.  The drive can then be accessed via USB.  Do you know the password for the encrypted drive?  If so, then if you can connect the drive to your computer you should be able to recover data from that drive.

Comment: No second drive bay unfortunately. Not even an optical drive bay to get one of those caddy's. I have a USB to SATA adapter. Yes I know the password. Yes I could recover data. The issue though is that there is around 1TB of personal data. That's not gonna be fitting on my new (~240GB) SSD.

Comment: If it were me, I would mount that drive ASAP and chroot the old system.  Then shut down the Manjaro X server and start the X server on the Mint partition to see how it runs.  Your problem may be much easier to pinpoint with targeted questions.  e.g. The Mint X server might not  run, there may be some other problem, boot logs might show errors, etc. etc.  Copying the data you want to save to a spare external drive might be an idea also, they sell for under $99 per TB nowadays.

Comment: Would that be possible via sata to usb? I've no spare hard drive bay in this laptop.

Comment: The USB to SATA adapter is your window to success.  The drive on the adapter appears like any other and can be mounted.  Review the logs (/var/log) to see if there is something that tells you what went wrong during the boot sequence.  The whole system be chroot'ed and run off the adapter, just don't bump it while in use.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing in the end. I was just hoping for some better solution. Thanks for the help.